# Card game similar to jokers and pegs

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

I recently read about a popular game that, similar to Jokers and Pegs, used cards to determine play. As I recall, it required multiple decks of cards - two more decks than the number of players, but I don't think it required a board of any kind. Supposedly easy to learn, suitable for adults or children, and about equal parts chance and skill. But for the life of me, I cannot recall the name. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Since Jokers and Pegs is a racing game, and thus requires some sort of equipment to keep track, I have no idea how you determined that the game without the equipment is "similar." What do you mean by "used cards to determine play?" This is pretty much every card game! Can you remember specifically what the winning condition or rules of play are?

Answer (score -1):

Head and foot is a game that uses multiple deck and has no required accessories or board.

Comment: Why do you think this is the game in question?